# githubmarkupが呼び込まれません。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, markdown

#### 前提・実現したいこと

github markupを実装したいです。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
LoadError in PageController#index
No such file to load -- github/markup
```

#### 該当のソースコード

手順1
github markupをインストールしました。
【ターミナル】

```
gem install github-markup
```

手順2
application_helperで呼び出しを行うコードを記述。
【application_helper.rb】

```
require 'github/markup'
GitHub::Markup.render('README.markdown', "* One\n* Two")
```

そしてサーバーを起動すると上記エラーが発生します。
記述箇所が間違っているのでしょうか？

#### 補足情報(言語/FW/ツール等のバージョンなど)

[github/markup](https://github.com/github/markup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決。

毎度すみません。

[こちら](https://github.com/github/markup)に書いてあるMarkup内の作業を全て行うことでエラーは出なくなりました。

```
easy_install docutils
Pod::Simple::HTML
```

に関してはsudoを入れると進めると思います。